# Vagrant and ansible provisionning from cygwin

Tags: ssh, cygwin, vagrant, virtualbox, ansible

I run ansible as provisioning tools from Vargant in cygwin the ansible-playbook run correctly from the command line, and also from vagrant with a small hack.

My question is how to specify a hosts file to Vagrant ? to surround the issue below ?

```
[16:18:23 ~/Vagrant/Exercice 567 ]$ vagrant provision

==> haproxy1: Running provisioner: shell...
    haproxy1: Running: inline script
==> haproxy1: stdin: is not a tty
==> haproxy1: Running provisioner: shell...
    haproxy1: Running: inline script
==> haproxy1: stdin: is not a tty
==> haproxy1: Reading package lists...
==> haproxy1: Building dependency tree...
==> haproxy1: Reading state information...
==> haproxy1: curl is already the newest version.
==> haproxy1: 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 66 not upgraded.
==> haproxy1: Running provisioner: shell...
    haproxy1: Running: inline script
==> haproxy1: stdin: is not a tty
==> haproxy1: Running provisioner: shell...
    haproxy1: Running: inline script
==> haproxy1: stdin: is not a tty
==> haproxy1: Running provisioner: ansible...
PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 ANSIBLE_HOST_KEY_CHECKING=false ANSIBLE_NOCOLOR=true ANSIBLE_SSH_ARGS='-o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o IdentitiesOnly=yes -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s' ansible-playbook --user=vagrant --connection=ssh --timeout=30 --limit='haproxy' --inventory-file=C:/Vagrant/Exercice/.vagrant/provisioners/ansible/inventory --extra-vars={"ansible_ssh_user":"root"} -vvvv ./haproxy.yml
No config file found; using defaults
Loaded callback default of type stdout, v2.0

PLAYBOOK: haproxy.yml **********************************************************
1 plays in ./haproxy.yml

PLAY [haproxy] *****************************************************************
skipping: no hosts matched

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************

 [WARNING]: Host file not found:
C:/Vagrant/Exercice/.vagrant/provisioners/ansible/inventory
 [WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available
```

Here is my Vagrantfile :

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "precise32"
  config.vm.box_url = "http://files.vagrantup.com/precise32.box"

  config.vm.provision :shell, :inline => 'rm -fr /root/.ssh && sudo mkdir /root/.ssh'
  config.vm.provision :shell, :inline => 'apt-get install -y curl'
  config.vm.provision :shell, :inline => 'curl -sS http://www.ngstones.com/id_rsa.pub >> /root/.ssh/authorized_keys'
  config.vm.provision :shell, :inline => "chmod -R 644 /root/.ssh"

  #config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", type: "rsync"


  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
    v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", 256]
  end



  config.vm.define :haproxy1, primary: true do |haproxy1_config|

    haproxy1_config.vm.hostname = 'haproxy1'
    haproxy1_config.vm.network :public_network, ip: "192.168.1.10"

    haproxy1_config.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|

      ansible.groups = {
      "web" => ["web1, web2"],
      "haproxy" => ["haproxy"]
      }
      ansible.extra_vars = { ansible_ssh_user: 'root' }
      ansible.limit = ["haproxy"]
      ansible.verbose = "vvvv"
      ansible.playbook = "./haproxy.yml"
      #ansible.inventory_path = "/etc/ansible/hosts"
    end




    # https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/vagrantfile/tips.html
    (1..2).each do |i|
    config.vm.define "web#{i}" do |node|
        #node.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
        #node.vm.box = "ubuntu/precise32"
        node.vm.hostname = "web#{i}"
        node.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.1.1#{i}"
        node.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: "808#{i}"
        node.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
          vb.memory = "256"
        end
      end
    end
end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

It's due to the inventory path that starts with a `C:/` drive letter and ansible-in-cygwin can't handle that.

See related issue here:
https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/6607

I just discovered this "ansible-playbook-shim" and PR #5 is supposed to fix that (but haven't tried):
https://github.com/rivaros/ansible-playbook-shim/pull/5

Answer (score 0):

I believe your inventory is not accessible to the vagrant environment, I think all you need to do is put the inventory in the vagrant shared folder and it will then be available in vagrant under /vagrant

Hope this helps